# Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to view function ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract MyContract{
    string value;

    function get() public returns(string memory){

        return value;
    } 
}
```

How to overcome this warning message ? Earlier I got "TypeError: Data location must be "memory"" message when I didn't mention the term "memory".

Answer (score 1):

I got you man

```
function get() public view returns(string memory){

    return value;
}
```

'view' just restricts the function to read only since you don't modify state at all

Comment: what do you mean ? I didn't understand